# Expand selection with brackets

Tags: sublimetext2

In ST2 we have Expand selection to brackets but if i need expand selection with brackets ? or more general expand selection with brackets, square brackets, curly braces ?

Comment: Please be more clear about what you want to accomplish.  As it stands, ST2 matches between square _and_ curly brackets using "ctrl+shift+m".

Comment: To brackets selects all before brackets and with brackets selects all within brackets and brackets also - i thought it's clear.

Comment: Just call "Expand Selection to Brackets" twice. My answer below has an explanation of what's happening and why that works.

Answer (score 7):

select brackets:
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>

select html tag wrap:
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

Comment: This answer is misleading and not helpful in a general scope. The question is not related to html. The correct answer is to hit ctrl+shift+m again to include the brackets.

Answer (score 3):

Sublime Text's **Expand Selection to Brackets** is designed to be called multiple times, it works as follows:

1. With nothing selected or an incomplete selection, the *contents* of first set of brackets will be selected.
2. If the selection contains the complete contents of a set of brackets, then expand the selection to include the enclosing brackets.
3. If the selection contains only a set of brackets and their contents, then expand the selection to include the parent's contents *and* containing brackets.

   - ***Note:*** Parent containers seem to be discovered backwards. Sometimes this switches the selection to a sibling container before traversing up a level. (see results 3 & 5 below)

Starting with a cursor in the nested comment in the following example, the list below describes selections resulting from calls to **Expand Selection to Brackets**.

```js
for (x in y) {
    if (x in z) {
        // start selection here
    }
}
```

1. Contents of if-statement curly braces are selected
2. If-statement curly braces are selected
3. If-statement condition is selected, including parentheses
4. For-statement contents are selected, including curly braces
5. For-statement argument is selected, including parentheses

I couldn't find any documentation to verify this. Selection results are consistent between ST2 and ST3.

Answer (score 0):

For lispers and clojurians. Here is the deal. Using macros.

```
[
    {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "brackets"}},
    {"command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}},
    {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "brackets"}},
    {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "brackets", "extend": true}}
]
```

Try to guess functions. For example, move_to has no direction, first invocation will move you forward but second move you backward. Ok move and forward: true but where backward ? again forward : false is backward. Terrible API. Also extend (why not select:true ?) will move with selection and without it just move somewhere.